# Javascript string.slice() works only once

Tags: javascript, slice

This has been driving me mad for hours, I'm sure I'm missing something simple, or maybe not.

I'm using Javascript to turn my personal homepage into a console like application. You can view it here: www.fort-hub.com

I'm mapping key strokes and have backspace (keycode 8) to change the `innerHTML` property of the console input `div` called `#in` to have one less end character via `slice()` like so:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang='en-gb'>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>FortHUB</title>
<link href="ss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">   
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"> 

</head>

<body>

<div id="console">
    <div id="out"><h1>Welcome to fort-hub console</h1></div>

    <div id="in">
        <span id="text"></span><span id="cursor"><</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="fH.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
/* Globals */
var _NL_ = '>';
var consoleIn = document.getElementById('text');
var consoleOut = document.getElementById('out');

/* Func in question */
function keyPress(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var e = event || window.event;
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var keyChar;

    var allowedChars = new Array();
    allowedChars[0] = 8; /* backspace */
    allowedChars[1] = 13; /* return */
    allowedChars[2] = 32; /* space */

    /* Alphanumeric range only */
    if(key > 46 && key < 90 || inArray(allowedChars, key) === true)
    {
        keyChar = String.fromCharCode(key);
        var input = trim(consoleIn.innerHTML);
        /* Map backspace */
        if(key === 8)
        {
               consoleIn.innerHTML = input.slice(0, -1);
        }
        ...
        consoleIn.innerHTML += keyChar.toLowerCase();
    }
    ...
}
```

So, please test this out by going to the URL, typing something in and pressing backspace. One char will be removed but repeat backspaces will not remove the rest of the string's chars.

Comment: I got an SSL connection error when I viewed the site. Can you make a JSfiddle?

Comment: Sorry about that. Care to try it again? I deleted my .htaccess that was outdated and referring to SSL I no longer use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the pressed key was backspace, you remove the last character from the `input` (and set the innerHTML to `remain`), yet you still add the `keyChar` to the `innerHTML`. This appends `\x08` (doesn't show up depending on font and browser, isn't accepted as input by Stackoverflow).

Add a `return` statement right after the `consoleIn.innerHTML = input.slice(0, -1);` to abort the keypress-handler.

Answer (score 4):

You're appending the actual backspace character code (`0x08`) to your element after you've deleted the last character. It is not rendered by the browser, but the next time you try to delete the last character again, you actually delete that backspace character instead, and immediately add a new backspace character.

You should not append the control characters that you have handled to your element's `innerHTML`.